# flash actionscript error 5007 while file is not linked or included in any way

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I created an xfl file called myfile.xfl and linked it to Main.as. 
Because my script is kind of extensive, I planned to distribute it over several as-files.

The Main.as looks like this and is linked correctly from the xfl-file:

```
package  {

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.xml.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var bestand:String;

        var titelFont:Font = new Titelfont();
        var werkFont:Font = new Werkfont();
        var titelfmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var werkfmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var inputfmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

        var snd:Sound;
        var cnl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

        var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        var myList:XML;

        var introClip:Containerclip = new Containerclip();
        var dicteeClip:Containerclip = new Containerclip();

        public function Main()
        {           
            //DE INFORMATIE UIT DE URL //
            //bestand = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters["bestand"];
            //bestand +=  ".xml";
            bestand = "xml/bron.xml"
            loadXml();
        }
        function loadXml():void
        {
            xmlLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(bestand));         
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
        }
        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            myList = new XML(event.target.data);
            myList.ignoreWhite = true;

            createTextFormat();
            createIntro();
            createDictee();
            createResultaten();
        }   
        include "CreateStuff.as"
        include "Dictee.as"
    }   
}
```

You can see my includes at the end: createstuff.as and dictee.as.
I was working on a third include, called **Sound.as**, and tried to preview my file when error 5007 popped up. "5007: An ActionScript file must have at least one externally visible definition"

I removed the `include Sound.as` line from my Main.as, thinking that must have cause the problem for some reason. When I republished the error popped up again, and flash automatically reopened the Sound.as file. While there is no link from anywhere to it anymore.

My other files are **CreateStuff.as** :

```
function createTextFormat() : void {
    titelfmt.size = 32;
    titelfmt.color = 0x003399;
    titelfmt.font = titelFont.fontName;

    werkfmt.size = 24;
    werkfmt.color = 0x000000;
    werkfmt.font = werkFont.fontName;

    inputfmt.size = 32;
    inputfmt.color = 0x333333;
    inputfmt.font = werkFont.fontName;
    //inputfmt.
}
function createTextfield (fmt) : TextField {
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.defaultTextFormat = fmt;

    if (fmt == titelfmt) {
        tf.multiline = false;
        tf.autoSize = "center";
        tf.selectable = false;
        tf.y = 10;
        tf.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    } else if (fmt == werkfmt) {
        tf.autoSize = "left";
        tf.multiline = true;    
    } else if (fmt == inputfmt) {
        tf.multiline = true;
        tf.width = 300;
        tf.height = 40;
        tf.border = true;
        tf.borderColor = 0xCCCCCC;
        tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT; 
    }
    return (tf);
}
function createIntro() : void {
    introClip.x = 0;
    introClip.y = 0;
    introClip.name = "introClip";

    var nttf:TextField = createTextfield(titelfmt);
    nttf.text = "Instructie"
    introClip.addChild(nttf);

    var itf:TextField = createTextfield(werkfmt);
    itf.text = "Wat weet jij nog?\nLuister naar de woorden.\nSchrijf ze op.";
    itf.width = 300;
    itf.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - 150;
    itf.y = 120;
    itf.selectable = false;
    introClip.addChild(itf);

    var startBtn:Beginknop = new Beginknop();
    startBtn.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - startBtn.width / 2;
    startBtn.y = 300;
    startBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showDictee);
    introClip.addChild(startBtn);

    addChild(introClip);
}
function createResultaten() : void {

}
```

And **Dictee.as** :

```
function createDictee () : void {
    dicteeClip.x = 0;
    dicteeClip.y = 0;

    var nttf:TextField = createTextfield(titelfmt);
    nttf.text = "Dictee"
    dicteeClip.addChild(nttf);

    var iptf:TextField = createTextfield(inputfmt);
    iptf.x = 135;
    iptf.y = 205;
    dicteeClip.addChild(iptf)

    var dicteeSpeaker:Luidspreker = new Luidspreker();
    dicteeSpeaker.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - dicteeSpeaker.width/2;
    dicteeSpeaker.y = iptf.y - dicteeSpeaker.height - 40;
    //dicteeSpeaker.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playSnd);
    dicteeSpeaker.name = dicteeSpeaker;
    dicteeClip.addChild(dicteeSpeaker);

    var volgendeKnop:Controleknop = new Controleknop();
    volgendeKnop.x = iptf.x + iptf.width + 30;
    volgendeKnop.y = iptf.y;
    dicteeClip.addChild(volgendeKnop);
}
function showDictee(event:MouseEvent) : void {
    addChild(dicteeClip);
    removeChild(introClip);
    speelDictee();
}
function speelDictee() : void {
    //bepaal geluid
    //afspelen geluid
    //volgende knop-actie
}
```

I initially called the file **Sound.as** but thought the error might come from that Sound is a reserved word, so I changed it to **Sounds.as**
I'm well out of my depth here and I have no clue why the error pops up. Or the file Sound.as while it is not linked.

My flash version is Flash-CC but the tag doesn't exist yet so I couldn't specify it in the tags.

Comment: I suppose you have cleaned the project after clearing the include?

Comment: @PeteTNT TNT, since I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to, the answer is probably no. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I read it too fast and thought that it was FlashBuilder project. I meant that if the Sound.as reference is cached somewhere, it would cause the error still. Either make a fresh project and try to see if it happens there again, or maybe try commenting these lines, var snd:Sound; and import flash.media.Sound; out temporarily to see if the Flash program is just erm... confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this question because for some reason the error disappeared and I have no idea why. I don't want to leave it open, I'd prefer to delete it as it's of no use to anyone but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**#5007** is commonly caused by

- Not correctly using a `package`
- **Including an `import` statement any level below the `package` level**